# How to avoid to manually set the initial value of a variable in a recursive function?

Tags: python

I found this solution for the Euler project 5 (What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?) with a variable range of integer values to divide evenly by:

```
def Euler5(start, end, counter):
    x = counter
    while start <= end:
        if x%counter == x%start:
            return Euler5(start+1, end, x)
        else:
            x += counter
    return x
```

I do however have to manually set the counter to the smallest integer value (initial `counter` = `start` value). Is there a way to automatically do this and to maintain the algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you right, you want that `counter == start` for the initial call without specifying the `counter` manually in the first call.

For this, you can set `counter` to a default value of `None` and check for this at the beginning of the function, setting `counter` to the appropriate value if this is the case:

```
def Euler5(start, end, counter=None):
    if counter is None:
        counter = start

    x = counter
    while start <= end:
        if x % counter == x % start:
            return Euler5(start+1, end, x)
        else:
            x += counter
    return x
```

Comment: I'd appreciate an upvote if that is indeed the case. ;)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it.